# Expected Value of Locality

Tags: memory, permutation, localityofreference

---

[image: Problem image]

---

In this problem, I am asked to find the expected value of locality. I understand how the answer to the problem is

`(n - 1) * (expected value of |π(i) − π(i − 1)|)`.

The problem solutions states that the expected value of

`|π(i) − π(i − 1)| is (n + 1) / 3`.

I do not understand this part of the solution. Could someone please explain this reasoning? 
Thank you.

---

[image: Problem Solution]

---

Comment: What is your programming question?

Comment: You're better off at https://math.stackexchange.com/